# How to programmatically create custom display suite field in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to move my code from the interface of Drupal for my custom display suite fields and place them into a custom module. I enabled my custom module and flushed cache and I cannot find the fields I have created in the Manage display tab for my node field or my taxonomy term field:

```
function my_module_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['taxonomy_term']['properties']['district_address'] = array(
    'label' => t('District address'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'getter callback' => 'district_address_callback',
    'entity views field' => TRUE
  );
  $info['node']['properties']['biography'] = array(
    'label' => t('Biography'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'getter callback' => 'biography_callback',
    'entity views field' => TRUE
  );
}

/**
 * Custom district address getter callback
 */
function district_address_callback($entity) {
  $street = $entity->field_address['und'][0]['street'];
  $output = '<div class="container">' . $street . '</div>';
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Custom biography getter callback
 */
function biography_callback($entity) {
  dpm($entity);
  $output = '<div class="container"><p>Biography goes here ...</p></div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: `&$info` is a reference, you don't have to return its value.

Comment: Q: Where do you expect to find your fields? Probably you need to define your fields in `hook_node_load` as well, see: [Cannot Find property after adding it with hook_entity_property_info_alter (callback not firing)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/96133/1908) at Drupal SE

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kenorb. Correct me if I am wrong but if I define a custom field in code I should also be able to to see my field in Drupal's interface under the entity that I have attached the field to. In this case, there would be a field available in the Manage display tab of a content type or a taxonomy vocabulary that I can then enable and display in a view mode of my choice. I will look into the link that you provided above and get back with you.